# Allowing CRAFT_TEMPLATE_PATH in index.php from .env variable

Tags: config, environmentvariables

It appears on Craft 3.1.8 that I can't set the CRAFT_TEMPLATE_PATH from .env without throwing a PHP notice error. This appears to be because the .env is loaded after the defines and I want to access the .ENV for my CRAFTENV_template path.

How can I set CRAFT_TEMPLATE_PATH from my .env without producing an error/warning?

Answer (score 0):

If you add it after you load the dot env stuff in your public index.php file, it should work:

```
// Load dotenv?
if (file_exists(CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/.env')) {
    (new Dotenv(CRAFT_BASE_PATH))->load();
}

define('CRAFT_TEMPLATE_PATH', getenv('CRAFT_TEMPLATE_PATH'));
```

Comment: I had assumed that my be a bad idea after the autoload but it was still throwing an error. But could be my stack issue. Will take another look